# How to return a string that is JSON formatted through Web Api Controller without having escape characters show up in the response

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have the following c# string that is JSON formatted.

```
string myString = "{color: \"red\", value: \"2\"}";
```

When I send this string as a response from my Controller it returns to the client with the escape characters intact.

Here is the code for my Controller I am using to return the string:

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{

    [HttpPost]
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
         string myString = "{color: \"red\", value: \"2\"}";
         HttpResponseMessage response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, myString, "application/json");
         return response;
    }
}
```

My questions is: **How do I return the string 'myString' to the client without the escape characters showing up on the client end?**

Thank you!

Comment: They shouldn't show up on the client end because those escape characters aren't encoded into the string. They should simply be evaluated by the compiler.

Comment: Found an answer for your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097841/return-a-json-string-explicitly-from-asp-net-webapi

Answer (score 0):

Assume your using Web-API, it returns data by default in Json format which is escaped, you can get Web-API to return XML, but either way it will be formatted one way or the other, looks like you need to de-serialise the Json and then it will remove the escaped chars.

Comment: I know there is a way to deliver the content to the client and not see the escape characters. I have seen it. My opinion is that the client does not need to deserialize the json.

Comment: Hi, what is your client aspx html/js , will try n drop u the code ?