# ApiController to return JSON string as-is

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a function in `ApiController`, which is supposed to output an object of some kind. That function receives that object in already serialized format. In order for the function to end up returing valid JSON, I need to turn it into `JObject`, like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object MyFunction()
    {
        string result = .......;
        return JObject.Parse(result);
    }
```

Question is: the result is *already* a valid JSON, and I want to return it as-is, without any more processing. If my class was a regular `Controller`, I could have just returned a `ContentResult`, but for some reasons, I cannot turn `ApiController` into regular `Controller` in this case.

Any other options?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17097919/368552

Comment: That worked, thanks. Can you submit it as an answer so that I can mark resolved?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the action returns a [System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.aspx), ASP.NET Web API converts the return value directly into an HTTP response message, using the properties of the HttpResponseMessage object to populate the response.

This option gives you a lot of control over the response message.

Example usage of returning raw json:
(**Reference** https://stackoverflow.com/a/17097919/368552)

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    string yourJson = GetJsonFromSomewhere();
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StringContent(yourJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    return response;
}
```

Comment: I wonder why they didn't just allow us to use ContentResult and Content(myString, "application/json") like in MVC...