# Differing behavior with $.post(...) between MVC controller and WebAPI controller

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

was writing an MVC application over the weekend and decided that part of the application should use WebAPI, i had the following javascript which calls a simple MVC Controller action

```
    $.post("/App/TestDb", request, function (data) {
        if (data.status == "SUCCESS") {
            alert(data.msg);
            $("#installBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            alert(data.msg);
        }
    }, "json");
```

When this returns the value `data` is represented as a JSON object. When i ported my code over to WebAPI the result in `data` was a string (i.e. `"{\"status\":\"SUCCESS\",\"msg\":\"Test\"}"`)

The MVC controller method below (removed other code to keep example simple)

```
public string TestDb(string appDb, string appUsername, string appPassword, string appHost)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { status = "SUCCESS", msg = "Test" });
    }
```

And the WebAPI controller method below

```
[HttpPost]
public string TestDb([FromBody] TestDbDTO testDb)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { status = "SUCCESS", msg = "Test" });
    }
```

As you can see from the above examples, both methods return exactly the same result. I am not sure if this is something i have (or have not) done correctly so my question is has anyone else encountered this?

Cheers

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097841/return-a-json-string-explicitly-from-asp-net-webapi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rewrite your API method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public object TestDb([FromBody] TestDbDTO testDb)
{
    return new { status = "SUCCESS", msg = "Test" };
}
```