# Relaying JSON has escaped double-quotes

Tags: c#, json, azure, azure-functions

I have a very simple C# Azure Function created in VS running locally that wraps the call to a 3rd party REST API for simplicity (*acts as a proxy, but not an **Azure Function Proxy***). All the function does after validating the supplied parameters is invoke the 3rd party REST API and directly return the results (JSON response) if the call is successful.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.PostAsync( requestUri, content );

if ( response.IsSuccessStatusCode )
{
    var jsonResponseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return req.CreateResponse( HttpStatusCode.OK, jsonResponseBody, "application/json" );
}
```

The resulting JSON that I get from invoking my Azure Function in Postman is similar to the following (internal double-quotes are string escaped):

```
"{\"Id\":\"0\",\"FirstName\":\"firstname\",\"LastName\":\"lastname\"}"
```

What could be causing this escaping to occur and how can I get rid of it?

Comment: Are you seeing the backslashes in the inspector? or actually in the HTML received data

Comment: For Azure In Process v4 Function you can return ContentResult.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/75798884/675079

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CreateResponse` will serialize whatever you give to it as JSON (or XML, if you ask to). If you give it string, it will wrap this string into extra `""` to make it valid JSON (or in an XML tag), like in all HelloWorld examples. So

```
req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello " + name)
```

returns HTTP response `"Hello User"`, because `Hello User` won't be valid JSON. The function doesn't care that your string is already a valid JSON.

To return string content as-is, you need to ask for that explicitly:

```
var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Content = new StringContent(jsonResponseBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return response;
```